# oracle sql, id's, group by one column, mulitple distinct in other column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, window-functions

I am trying to figure out how to write a query to do this. I have two ID's in the table ID1 and ID2. Below is what I want.

Want

1. ID2 has count(ID2)>1
2. count of distinct ID1 >1

I am not sure how to do this with Oracle SQL. I did write code to do the group by. However, I am having trouble getting the rest of the code to work, including the part where the count of distinct ID1>1. I will post more code once I get more code done.

Data

```
ID1 ID2
1   33
1   33
5   44
6   44
7   8
```

Want

```
ID1 ID2
5   44
6   44
```

Attempt Code

```
select ID2, 
COUNT(*) 
from TABLE1 
GROUP BY ID2
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the entire rows, you can use window functions. Unlike several other databases, Oracle supports `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` as a window function so that's easy with:

```
select id1, id2
from (select t.*, count(distinct id1) over(partition by id2) cnt from mytable t)
where cnt > 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06f81a9f408f04d85c7c3f8604e9c95d)**:

```
ID1 | ID2
--: | --:
  5 |  44
  6 |  44
```

Comment: @jarlh: yes - so that was more interesting too :)